# API requests require HTTP BASIC AUTH in PRE-EMPTIVE mode for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone 8 app. I need to call api in Preemptive mode. I am using the following code but I am getting 401-Unauthorised exception.

```
    async public static Task<string> Get(string url)
    {

        try

        {
            string content = string.Empty;

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            string userCredentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}",Constants.USERNAME, Constants.PASSWORD);

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userCredentials);

            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "basic " + base64);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("application", Constants.APP_NAME);
            var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Can any one tell me how I can call HTTP BASIC AUTH in PRE-EMPTIVE mode? or what I am doing wrong in the above code?

Comment: Have you tried using the explicit [`Authorization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.authorization(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the request headers rather than trying to just add a separate header?

Comment: how i can add explicit Authorization? could you pls explain it with some example?

Comment: I mean that there's a property you can assign:  `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = ...`

Comment: I just tried  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(base64); but its not working. I am getting same resule of 401 exception